# Tableau dynamic filtering and visualization

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a few questions about Tableau and how dynamic it is:

1. Changes to the data in a relational db requires refresh, no events of refresh or something else?
2. Can we have visualizations at a runtime, e.g if we have some filters and we select some of them are the visualizations going to be updated?

If I have some API and want it to accept some params from the users and pass them to Tableau for querying, this would be a use case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tabeau queries your data source directly. Changes in your source are visible whenever Tableau launches a query.
   There is no "in memory" database to be refreshed, but there are high performance extracts that can function as a buffer between your data source & Tableau, sometimes approaching in memory performance.

A "new" query to get fresh data is sent when:

- Something changes, for example the user filters a view (see question 2 :-) )
- The workbook or dashboard is opened
- The refresh button is hit
- Another periodic refresh is launched
- A programmatic event triggers a refresh

It is possible to launch a reload of the extract or a new query based on a trigger. You could create a command line script on the server that is triggered by your source system to reload (using TABCMD - Tableau command line interface or TabPy - Tableau Python integration amongst other thing). Or you could use the API.

2. Yes, the visualizations will be updated each time you select a filter.
   This behavior is very customizable, you have a lot of control on what filter refreshes what viz, even in the front end only.

EDITED for clarity

Comment: Thanks for the answer, right now I have a Tableau online instance, and the Bridge, so is it possible to connect my local data source over Bridge to Tableau online maybe?

Comment: Ah not sure how the bridge works, but in general when you use a "static" file, you need to reload the file. It's not very procatical or intuitive like with a DB. There might be workaround but I don't know them